# Best practice for custom fields added to standard objects in Managed Package

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, bestpractice, schema

We have a requirement wherein we need to have certain custom attributes in the Account object within our Managed Package being deployed onto an existing SFDC set up. These attributes are readable and writeable from within the Managed Package. We have followed an object design principle to create new custom objects whenever writeable fields are needed within the managed package. So, for this case, we have created a new custom object within the context of the package which shares a Master-Detail relationship with the Account object and has its custom fields within.

Rationale behind this design:

1. Accounts fields which are writeable within managed package localized to the new custom object
2. Existing Account object has many custom attributes used within the CRM system. The fields include a set of ten look up fields as well. Our requirement includes around four to five look up fields. Having a separate custom object helps to avoid extendability issues by adding to the field restrictions of 25 look up fields in the object when new fields are added
3. The managed package also uses data from the standard account fields which are feasible through the master-detail relationship with the new custom object

The one disadvantage here is the additional records of the custom objects in the managed package

Can anyone please confirm the best practice to be followed for this scenario? Any references to documentation around schema design for managed packages covering the above mentioned topic is much appreciated.